# Angular UI Router pausing before child state controller execution

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-controller

I know that a child state / controller can wait for needed async results by adding a promise object to the the resolve object in its state description object. But using this means that the decision of what is required for the state is made before the controller runs. where in my case I need to apply logic to decide if I need any async data at all or not and what this data should be. 
I also understand that I can put this logic in a service but this would mean moving all the logic from the controller to a corresponding service [which IS an option but feels "wrong"].

In my scenario I would like a parent state to be able to postpone the execution flow and not have his child state controllers execute until it finished preparing some content for them.

Setting up a promise on the scope and waiting for it on the child state would work only if the child state itself does not have child states of its own [because in this pattern the child controller DOES execute and the execution would continue to its decedent states where again I would again have to add a promise to make them actually run their code when the promise is resolved].

I also know that I could probably catch the next `StateChangeStarted` event, set `event.preventDefault=true` and later on use `$urlRouter.sync()` it the resolve of the promise on the parent state. but it feels rather awkward to do so.

I would like to be able to do something like `$urlRouter.pause()` [no such API is available at the time of writing the Q]  to prevent the router from continuing and then being able to call `$urlRouter.sync()`.

What would be the "Angular way" way to conditionally pause the execution of child states controllers until some async results are resolved by a parent state?

Comment: FYI, this sounds exactly like a job for chained resolves.  The result of parent resolves can be injected into child resolves (once the parent resolve has finished). What logic is your controller doing that doesn't feel right to factor out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wrote this Q I have adopted a perspective that it would not be a good idea for the parent state to block the execution of the child state.

The reason is that even when it seems like the parent state knows that the child state MUST have some data prepared for it so it can do its stuff, it is at least possible that there are other stuff that the child state can do until said required data becomes available.

My best example would be a parent state that prepares data to be displayed on a map - even though it is clear that the child sate can not complete rendering until it has the data from the parent - it can for sure start rendering the empty map and only add the data on the map when its available.

looking from this perspective neither resolve nor blocking the execution of the child state is a good idea.

What I ended up doing so far is having a promises service that keeps promises for data created by the parent to the $scope and using `$q.all($promisService.get(),...).then` or just `$promisService.get().then` as fits in each specific case.

That said, I am thinking of trying to attach the promises to the states $data property so they would cleanup automatically. It just that I can't find enough info on how the .data attribute behaves or should be used in a dynamic context

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use data in the child state that come from the parent state, I suggest that you set the data at the `$rootScope` level in the parent state controller, and in the child state you can watch `$rootScope` and populate your local scope with the data in `$rootScope`.

For example in parent controller:

`$rootScope.user = User.get();`

In child controller:

```
 $scope.userData = {..};

 $rootScope.$watch('user', function(){
   //if somehow you need a local userData variable augmented with other types of data
   $scope.userData.email = $rootScope.user.email;
 });
```